# What is the difference between fullnameOverride and nameOverride in Helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I could find both fullnameOverride and nameOverride in Helm chart.Please help clarifying what is the difference between these two with an example.

Answer (score 55):

`nameOverride` replaces the name of the chart in the `Chart.yaml` file, when this is used to construct Kubernetes object names.  `fullnameOverride` completely replaces the generated name.

These come from [the template provided by Helm for new charts](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/e007c900ce5f2233c8583565d5ba1b0433b1a213/pkg/chartutil/create.go#L433-L449).  A typical object in the templates is named

```yaml
name: {{ include "<CHARTNAME>.fullname" . }}
```

If you install a chart with a deployment with this name, and where the `Chart.yaml` file specifies `name: chart-name`...

- `helm install release-name .`, the Deployment will be named `release-name-chart-name`
- `helm install release-name . --set nameOverride=name-override`, the Deployment will be named `release-name-name-override`
- `helm install release-name . --set fullnameOverride=fullname-override`, the Deployment will be named `fullname-override`

The generated `...fullname` template is (one code branch omitted, still from the above link)

```
{{- define "<CHARTNAME>.fullname" -}}
{{- if .Values.fullnameOverride }}
{{- .Values.fullnameOverride | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- else }}
{{- $name := default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride }}
{{- printf "%s-%s" .Release.Name $name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

So if `fullnameOverride` is provided, that completely replaces the rest of the logic in the template.  Otherwise the name is constructed from the release name and the chart name, where `nameOverride` overrides the chart name.

Comment: Is it (always) considered a bad-practice to override it?

Comment: Feels like this is trying to cover all possible use cases, turning into a needlessly confusing complication for most deployments.

Comment: The charts I generally work on were written before this was part of the standard template, and don't have this option.  That having been said, I also get a lot of requests for various parts of the chart to be overridden in various ways, and the only way to allow this is via settings in the `values.yaml`.  If you don't need to specify this (and I agree, you usually won't) just don't provide the value.

Answer (score 0):

I tried (almost) all the options, my Helm version is 3 (v3.12.1);

Create a default image in a temporary local directory: `C:\_tmp\my-example>helm create my-stuff`

- Case 1: leave values.yaml with empty values

`nameOverride: ""`

`fullnameOverride: ""`

From the folder created by Helm, execute the install command with the ‘generate-name’ option:

```
C:\_tmp\my-example\my-stuff>helm install --generate-name ./ --values ./values.yaml
```

This will install the nginx basic example; the Deployment and Service name are automatically generated, e.g. `chart-1687255131-my-stuff`

- Case 2: leave values.yaml with empty values but specify the name in
  the command:
  `C:\_tmp\my-example\my-stuff>helm install case2 ./ --values ./values.yaml`

The difference from before is that the first part is not generated but the ‘case2’ value is used; from console or k8s command (kubectl get services) the generated service has been named `case2-my-stuff`

- Case 3: execute

  `C:\_tmp\my-example\my-stuff>helm install case3-from-command-line ./ --values ./values.yaml`

The result (deployment & service) is `case3-from-command-line-my-stuff`

- Case 4: override ‘name’ in values.yaml:

`nameOverride: "case4"`

`fullnameOverride: ""`

and execute

```
C:\_tmp\my-example\my-stuff>helm install case4-from-command-line ./ --values ./values.yaml
```

The result is `case4-from-command-line` (the nameOverride is ignored)

- Case 5: override ‘full name’ in values.yaml:

  `nameOverride: ""`

  `fullnameOverride: "case5"`

and execute

```
`C:\_tmp\my-example\my-stuff>helm install case5-from-command-line ./ --values ./values.yaml`
```

The result is `case5` (full name wins)

- Case 6: override both

  `nameOverride: "case6"`

  `fullnameOverride: "case6full"`

and execute

```
`C:\_tmp\my-example\my-stuff>helm install case6-from-command-line ./ --values ./values.yaml`
```

Like before, full name wins: `case6full`

- Case 7: override both but use --generate-name

  `nameOverride: "case7"`

  `fullnameOverride: "case7full"`

and execute

```
`C:\_tmp\my-example\my-stuff>helm install --generate-name ./ --values ./values.yaml`
```

The generate name option is ignored, `case7full` wins.

- Case 8: override only fullname, use --generate-name

  `nameOverride: ""`

  `fullnameOverride: "case8full"`

and execute

```
`C:\_tmp\my-example\my-stuff>helm install --generate-name ./ --values ./values.yaml`
```

The generate name option is ignored, `case8full` wins. This seems to me the best option, I still don't understand the actual role of nameOverride, maybe this is due to the version 3 overriding the beahviour of version 2.